# Ensuring triggered sync finishes before showing notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-syncadapter

I am developing an app that synchronizes data with a server using a [Sync Adapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html). When data changes on the server, I send notifications via GCM to android devices of the respective users. I also use these [notifications to trigger a sync](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html#RunByMessage).

If a user clicks on a notification, I want my app to show details of the corresponding data. For this to work, I need to have the triggered sync completed before the notification is clicked, so that the data is available locally.

How do I ensure this? Can I delay showing a notification until its triggered sync is completed? Or is there another way of solving this problem?

I thought about using either a `ContentObserver` or `SyncStatusObserver` for this. The former requires me to specify a content URI, which is not possible if I want to wait until everything is synchronized, while the latter can only be used to determine if a sync is pending or active, but not if one has succeeded.